# Odoo-one2many relation field mapping

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, psql

I know how to declare one2many relation field in Odoo but my doubt is how its working in back end(database) and  how its fetch or store in database.

can anyone explain detailed please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an invoice with several invoice lines you must create a field one2many in the model account.invoice:

```
'line_ids': fields.one2many ('account.invoice.line', 'invoice_id', 'Invoice Lines')
```

Also in the account.invoice.line model you must create a many2one field with the same name that is referenced in the one2many field:

```
'invoice_id': fields.many2one ('account.invoice', 'Invoice')
```

Now, at database level, the only change that will be shown is the invoice_id field of the invoice line (table account_invoice_line) which will store the invoice_id to which each line belongs.